# How to configure nginx, let some sub-domains can only visit js/css files?

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have a website(for example: test.com), which has 2 kinds of subdomains:

1. test.com
2. static_${version}.test.com

The 1st one is the main subdomain, and the 2nd one is only used for static files(js/css/image). The `${version}` is a version number, it is changed when there is new version of js/css/images files, I need it because the client may cache the old ones.

Now I use nginx, but I don't configure it about subdomains, just simply rewrite all subdomains to the main `test.com` domain.

It works, but one day I found a search engine, use the `static.test.com` as the main domain to visit my site.

How do I configure the nginx, to let the `static.test.com` can only visit static files, while the main domain can visit all?

---

**UPDATE**

I hope request of `static.test.com` with js/css/images will rewrite to `test.com`, not to a static file in disk. And other requests(not js/css/images) will return `404` directly.

Thanks for [Timofey Stolbov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591410/how-to-configure-nginx-let-some-sub-domains-can-only-visit-js-css-files/6591540#6591540), I write a config now:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^static_(.*)\.test\.com$;
    set $version $1;
    rewrite ^/public/(.*) http://test.com/public/$1?v=$version last;
    return 404;
}
```

Since my js/css/images files are all in "public" directory, so I just check if it starts with "public". If not, just return 404.

But I don't know is it correct, especially the `return 404`, or is there any better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use something like this.

```
server {
  server_name static.test.com;
  root /var/www/static;
  location / {
    rewrite ^/([^\/]+\.css)$ /css/$1 break;
    rewrite ^/([^\/]+\.js)$ /js/$1 break;
    rewrite ^/([^\/]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg))$ /images/$1 break;
  }
}
```

---

**For the second question**

Yes, your cofig is correct. But you should use permanent redirect or nginx will redirect request with `302 Moved Temporarily`. Also `listen 80` is implied by default.

I don't think that using redirect for every js/css/image is good idea, so think twice. :)

And here is config.

```
server {
    server_name ~^static_(.*)\.test\.com$;
    set $version $1;
    rewrite ^/public/(.*) http://test.com/public/$1?v=$version permanent;
    return 404;
}
```